# Sym(V ⊕ ∧² V) isomorphic to direct sum of all Schur functors of V

Tags: rt.representation-theory, schur-functions, young-tableaux, symmetric-functions

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional $K$-vector space. Then, the symmetric power $\mathrm{Sym}\left(V\oplus \wedge^2 V\right)$ is isomorphic to the direct sum of all Schur functors applied to $V$ (each one time only) as a Schur functor.

This follows by comparison of characters using the so-called Schur identity

$\sum\limits_{\lambda\text{ is a partition}} s_{\lambda} = \prod\limits_i \left(1-\xi_i\right)^{-1} \cdot \prod\limits_{i < j} \left(1-\xi_i\xi_j\right)^{-1}$,

where $s_{\lambda}$ denote the Schur "polynomials" and $\xi_i$ are countably many indeterminates (see, for instance, chapter 5.4 in ["M. Lothaire", *Algebraic Combinatorics on Words*](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~berstel/Lothaire/AlgCWContents.html)). While it is easy to like the Schur identity, it is hard not to dislike the proof of the "strong" isomorphism $\mathrm{Sym}\left(V\oplus \wedge^2 V\right)\cong \bigoplus\limits_{\lambda\text{ is a partition}} \mathrm{Schur}_{\lambda}\left(V\right)$ using the "weak" identity for Schur polynomials. Is there any better argument known? Maybe even one yielding a *canonical* isomorphism?

Answer (score 7):

Here is how I think it should go. First

$\mathrm{Sym}\left(V\oplus \wedge^2 V\right)\cong \mathrm{Sym}\left(V\right)\otimes \mathrm{Sym}\left(\wedge^2 V\right)$

Then we have

$\mathrm{Sym}\left(\wedge^2 V\right)\cong \sum\limits_{\lambda} \mathrm{Schur}_{\lambda}\left(V\right)$

where the sum is over partitions such that all parts of the conjugate partition are even. This came up in 
[Symmetric tensor products of irreducible representations](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13568/symmetric-tensor-products-of-irreducible-representations)

The tensor product $\mathrm{Sym}\left(V\right)\otimes \mathrm{Schur}_{\lambda}\left(V\right)$ is known by Pieri's rule.

Now given a partition we take a maximal subdiagram such that every column has an even number of boxes. The complement is skew shape with at most one box in each column.

**Further comment** In response to the request for representation theoretic proofs of the results used see

MR1606831 (99b:20073)  Goodman, Roe ;  Wallach, Nolan R.  Representations and invariants of the classical groups.
Encyclopedia of Mathematics and its Applications, 68. Cambridge University Press, Cambridge,  1998. xvi+685 pp. ISBN: 0-521-58273-3; 0-521-66348-2

In particular see 9.2.2 Reciprocity rules for Pieri's rule and see 5.2.6 to see the decomposition of $\mathrm{Sym}\left(\wedge^2 V\right)$. The highest weight vectors are constructed using Pfaffians.

Comment: Cool! Remains to get a character-free grip on the $\mathrm{Sym}^2\left(V\right)$ isomorphism and on Pieri's rule (again, both I can only prove using characters...).

Comment: With $\mathrm{Sym}^2\left(V\right)$ I meant $\mathrm{Sym}\left(\wedge^2 V\right)$...

Comment: Proving Pieri without characters is more or less equivalent to proving the reduction rule for representations of $S_n$ without characters. This is in some literature, I think, although I have never read such a proof.

Comment: You can find a character-free proof of the branching rule for $S_n$, also known as the reduction rule, in Theorem 2.8.3 (p. 77) of Sagan, "The Symmetric Group", GTM 203.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to think about it. It's equivalent to show that each dominant character of the Borel 
occurs with multiplicity one in the polynomial algebra on wedge-2(V) + V.
Now  multiplicity <= 1 because there is a Zariski dense orbit.
To see every one occurs:  write down explicit  polynomials
that correspond to fundamental weights (fun).

Comment: As for "explicit polynomials", have you done this or are you just assuming that it will be fun?

Comment: Time passes, anon still doesn't deliver?