# Symmetric Powers for Lie Algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $V_\lambda$ be the irreducible representation of $sl_{n}(\mathfrak{C})$ with highest  weight $\lambda$. There are well known formulas for the decomposition of $V_\lambda^{\otimes^k}= V_\lambda\otimes V_\lambda\otimes \cdots\otimes V_\lambda$ into irreducble representations using Littelwood-Richardson, or Littelmann paths, among others.

Is there any similar for the symmetric power $S^k(V_\lambda)$ or for $\wedge^k(V_\lambda)$, even for $sl_2(\mathfrak{C})$ or$k=3, 4$, or just some results in some cases??

I know that small cases can be computed, for instance using LiE
 http://wwwmathlabo.univ-poitiers.fr/~maavl/LiE/form.html
but this formulas seems to be recursive. Is there any closed formula like Littelwood-Richardson, or Littelmann paths?

What is the best recent reference?

Thanks

Comment: I think "plethysm" is the keyword you're looking for

Comment: The character of the exterior power should be something like $e_k[s_\lambda]$ and the symmetric power $h_k[s_\lambda]$

Comment: This doesn't necessarily mean there's a simple formula- plethysm in general is very hard to understand. But anyways, Richard Stanley should probably be here soon to tell you the answer.

Comment: even for $sl_2$, something general like   $S^3(V_n)$ there is not a simple closed formula, isn't it? Of course you can compute some cases, but even these case is hard. Am I right?

Comment: Giving a Littelmann path style description of this is a famous open problem.

Comment: For $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ the picture is a bit better than in general: There are explicit combinatorial constructions of crystals corresponding to $S^\lambda(V_n)$, from which you can read off the multiplicities. I guess in principle this means we have a positive combinatorial interpretation for plethysm coefficients $\langle s_\mu [s_\nu] , s_\lambda \rangle$ whenever $\lambda$ has at most two parts. Although I'm not sure the description is concise enough to count as a formula.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symmetric tensor products of irreducible representations](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13568/symmetric-tensor-products-of-irreducible-representations)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For $sl_2$ one has formulas. If $V_n=S^n(\mathbb{C}^2)$, then the multiplicity of the irreducible $V_k$ inside $S^m(V_n)$ is
$$
M_{m,n,k}=\left[m,n,\frac{mn-k}{2}\right]-\left[m,n,\frac{mn-k}{2}-1\right]
$$
where $[m,n,w]$ is the number of integer partitions of $w$ with at most $n$ parts of length $\le m$.
This is the Cayley-Sylvester formula. It was discovered by Cayley in a letter to Sylvester around 1854/1855 but only proved in 1878 by Sylvester (see [this article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0315086086900911)).

For simple cases like $S^3(V_n)\simeq S^n(V_3)$ (by Hermite's reciprocity of 1854) one has even more explicit formulas, see Theorem 1.3 in [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03166).

For $sl_n$, as far as I know the state-of-the-art is summarized in [this article](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10208-015-9275-7) by Khale and Michałek.