# Are isotypic components of $S(\mathfrak{g})$ finite-dimensional?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a complex simple Lie algebra. Let $S(\mathfrak{g})$ be the algebra of polynomial functions on $\mathfrak{g}$, viewed as a $\mathfrak{g}$-representation. Are the isotypic components of $S(\mathfrak{g})$ finite-dimensional?

This seems to be true for $\mathfrak{sl}_n$, since this is the subject of "plethysm" and there are explicit formulae for these multiplicities. See e.g. [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/299900/symmetric-powers-for-lie-algebras) mathoverflow question and the reference therein.

Comment: I think your reference is for a different problem and the statement you are asking about is false even for $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ and the trivial representation (and therefore for every f.d. irreducible representation).

Comment: @SimonWadsley Doesn't the trivial representation give you the algebra of invariant polynomials which has dimension $\mathrm{rank}(\mathfrak{g})$?

Comment: Well it is a polynomial algebra in that many variables. I wouldn't call that finite-dimensional.

Comment: @SimonWadsley: the question asks about the finite-dimensionality of the *isotypic components*, not the whole representation.

Comment: Yes. But the invariant polynomials form a polynomial algebra in rank $\mathfrak{g}$ (that is the dimension of a Cartan) variables and are the isotypic component corresponding to the trivial representation. Or am I completely misunderstanding the question?

Comment: Note that for plethysm, one considers $\mathfrak{gl}(n)$. The additional central element gives a grading, so each isotypic component of $S(\mathfrak g)$ is contained in $S^n(\mathfrak g)$  for some $n$.

Comment: Well, define "finite dimensional". The following is true: Each isotypic component is a free module of finite rank over the algebra $S(\mathfrak g)^G$ of invariants. Moreover, the latter is a polynomial ring in finitely many variables. That's all the finiteness and freeness you can have. The first fact is due to Kostant, the second to Chevalley (I believe).

Comment: @FriedrichKnop Is it easy to see the first fact? Also, is it possible to determine the rank in terms of the representation type?

Comment: @leibnewtz The first fact is not easy. It follows from the flatness of $S(\mathfrak g)$ as a $S(\mathfrak g)^G$-module which in turn can be deduced from the equidimensionality of the categorical quotient $\mathfrak g\to\mathfrak g/\!/G$. Second question: Let $V$ be a simple $\mathfrak g$-module. Then the rank of the corresponding isotypical component equals the dimension of the zero weight space $\dim V^T$ of $V$. All this is due to Kostant "Lie group representations on polynomial rings".

Comment: @FriedrichKnop Great, thanks! Maybe you could consider posting this as an answer, since it seems to answer the spirit of the original question in the affirmative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there must be some different ideas of what your question means, looking at the comments. I understood it to mean as in the decomposition of tensor powers of a $\mathfrak{g}$-representation into irreducible subrepresentations. In which case, the answer is a definite yes. For a start, the action of $\mathfrak{g}$ on any symmetric power of a representation preserves the degree. So in this way $S(\mathfrak{g}) = \bigoplus_{i=0}^\infty S^{i}(\mathfrak{g})$. Then the isotypic components in this sense just refers to the decomposition of these finite dimensional pieces into irreducibles which are automatically finite dimensional themselves. The explicit decompositions themselves can be quite hard to work out although there are formulae for these things. This is the kind of thing that "plethysm" refers to.

The invariant polynomials in this view form trivial subrepresentations but they would not be regarded as a single isotypic component (indeed they appear at various degrees and there are more than $\mathrm{rank}\ \mathfrak{g}$ of them, those are just the generators)

Edit: having looked through the edits to the question I understand the confusion a little better. You originally asked about whether copies of each irreducible appeared finitely many times. I would hesitate to call these isotypic components but the answer here is no. As pointed out in the comments the collection of all trivial subreps form an infinite-dimensional component. This is, in essence, the span of all polynomials generated by the Casimir elements.